# Processing Laravel job with many HTTP requests inside, it fails trying by timeout

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-5.8, laravel-seeding, laravel-jobs

I have an API REST built using Laravel 5.8 framework.

I have to get the data for my app from a public REST API. For this, i have to do a lot of requests. I made a seeder what do this, and it takes 2 minutes for the entire migration data process approximately (take from the public Api and insert in my application database).

I cant run the seeder by a cronjob because it does not work (it looks like need an user to execute the command to work). So, i created a job class what i call from my kernel file, the queue configuration was seted as database (`QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`), like a scheduled task (to execute with Supervisor: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration).

Despite this, the job fails, because it takes a long time to execute, so my data is not updated.

What i can do process my jobs by batch successfully?

This is my kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use App\Jobs\Seed\ApiPlayerStatisticJob;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        //
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->job(new ApiPlayerStatisticJob)->everyFiveMinutes();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

My ApiPlayerStatisticJob.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Seed;

use App\ApiExternal;
use App\ApiPlayer;
use App\ApiTeam;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class ApiPlayerStatisticJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $api_teams = ApiTeam::get();
        foreach ($api_teams as $api_team) {
            // echo 'TEAM: '.$api_team->id;
            $api_external_players = ApiExternal::getTeamPlayerStatistics($api_team->id);
            foreach ($api_external_players as $api_external_player) {
                // echo PHP_EOL.'PLAYER: '.$api_external_player['id'];
                $api_player = ApiPlayer::find($api_external_player['id']);
                if ($api_player != null) {
                    $api_player->update($api_external_player);
                    // echo PHP_EOL.'> PLAYER UPDATED ';
                } else {
                    // echo PHP_EOL.'X PLAYER DIDNT UPDATED ';
                }
            }
            // echo PHP_EOL;
            // echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

And my Seeder what i used for construct my job (by replication, excluding the print expressions):

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

use App\ApiExternal;
use App\ApiPlayer;
use App\ApiTeam;

class ApiPlayerStatisticsSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $api_teams = ApiTeam::get();
        foreach ($api_teams as $api_team) {
            echo 'TEAM: '.$api_team->id;
            $api_external_players = ApiExternal::getTeamPlayerStatistics($api_team->id);
            foreach ($api_external_players as $api_external_player) {
                echo PHP_EOL.'PLAYER: '.$api_external_player['id'];
                $api_player = ApiPlayer::find($api_external_player['id']);
                if ($api_player != null) {
                    $api_player->update($api_external_player);
                    echo PHP_EOL.'> PLAYER UPDATED ';
                } else {
                    echo PHP_EOL.'X PLAYER DIDNT UPDATED ';
                }
            }
            echo PHP_EOL;
            echo PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the static function `ApiExternal::getTeamPlayerStatistics(int id)` do all requests necessaries to get th data (like 30 requests), so what i can do to process this job (or the seeder directly) in background without it fails?

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure the `config/queue.php` file correctly?

Quote from the documentation in the [Job expirations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#job-expirations-and-timeouts) paragraph:

> In your config/queue.php configuration file, each queue connection defines a retry_after option. This option specifies how many seconds the queue connection should wait before retrying a job that is being processed.